# after yielding the first item how to call the first parse function again with different parameters to yield an other item

Tags: python, parsing, web-scraping, scrapy, scrapy-shell

i think my question is clear from title, i created a spider with multiple parsing function in which i pass my item in their parameters and in last one i just `yield item` to save it in json file, 
i want to run the spider automatically again with all parsing methods to build new item . 
i tried to do it with for loop from the start parse function :

```
def parse (self,response):
  for i in [6,7]:
    yield Request(url =  "link",
                  callback=self.parseItem,
                  meta={'parametre': i, }
                        )    


def parseItem(self, response):
  i = response.meta.get('parametre')
  #first parse

#spider functions
```

also i tried recalling the first parse function after yielding my item at last parse function

```
        print(" no more attributes to add / item ready to add to json file")
        yield item
        yield Request(url =  "link",
                  callback=self.parseItem,
                  meta={'parametre': 7, }
                        )
```

and both solutions did not work , what happens exactly that i find only my first item with first parametre in my output and the spider doesnt build the second item with the second parametre, any help please

Comment: is the second url the same as the original one? In that case you can yield your request like this: `Request(url =  "link", callback=self.parseItem, meta={'parametre': 7, 
dont_filter=True)` to make sure scrapy doesn't filter out the duplicate request

Comment: thank u so much sir it worked i just added dont_filter=True to all scrapy.Requests , you saved my code twice in 3 days :)